# vs2010 - Can not open include file 'sys/param.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When i compile my C++ solution in vs2010 x64 mode, i get the below compilation issue.
`Can not open include file 'sys/param.h' :No such file or directory.`

But the same compiles fine in Win32 mode.

I am not sure how this header file is missing.Can any one help me on this?
I am using some of the client headers and this is the below code section that is present in the client file.
   `#ifndef WIN32

    #include <sysipc.h>

    #include <sys/param.h>

    #endif`

Comment: Try check directories options in project properties on both plaform (you can add some path to win32 settings, but not add to x64). Check Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories, and C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Comment: @user1837009: I'm pretty sure that's NOT the problem.

Comment: it sounds like someone removed the `WIN32` macro from the preprocessor in the project file. That macro **MUST** be defined as an API target even on `WIN64` (which should be defined concurrently along with `_WIN64`).

Answer (score 2):

This is highly likely a consequence of some `#if` going wrong - e.g. it's checking for `_M_IX86`, and it not being set on a 64-bit system, it picks up something non-windows and tries to compile that.

`sys/param.h` is a unix/linux header-file, and you shouldn't expect to find that in your Windows system. [edit: unless you hooked in a version of the GNU compiler or did some other modification to the compilation tools core of your MSVC build environment]

Unfortunately, without seeing the source code, all we can possibly do is explain the possible reasons...

Comment: I suspect there is more around that needed. Is this some open source software? If so what?

Comment: @Mats..its not open source..its the dependant team code, i m using. Previulsy i wrongly edited.Now its correct. Unfortunately i am not supposed to share the code here.But here i have one question is though i am running the application in Windows with x64 mode, how its going inside the #ifndef section.

Comment: Looks like you should have `#if !(defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))` instead of `#ifndef WIN32`. Or `#ifndef _WIN32` should work too - that's defined for both 32 and 64-bit windows according to MS's website.

Answer (score 2):

The include `#include <sysipc.h>` should be `#include <sys/ipc.h>`, however, this is a POSIX header file that is meant for Linux build projects so it won't work for any Visual Studio projects. Since you're compiling for x64, WIN32 flags might not be set by default.

Try changing the macro to:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#endif // !_MSC_VER
```

Hope that helps.